# How do I make a "published" Google Doc private?

Tags: google-docs

I'm new to Google Docs. I recently "published to web" one of my Docs as an experiment.  However, I don't want anyone to be able to view this webpage, only specified users.

The reason why I wanted to publish the Doc is because I want to be able to link to that Doc from other documents.  Basically I want to build a website and use my Google Docs as webpages.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the same steps that you followed to publish to the web? AFAIK there you will find and option to unpublish. By the other hand, the question looks to be too broad as it actually includes two questions.

Comment: I don't want to "unpublish" it.  I want it published but can only be seen by authorized users.